# Iterating through Excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Here is my code. I'm new to VBA so, I am unsure how to iterate through multiple pages.

Here's my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Sub spellCheck()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Cells.CheckSpelling
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (this will simply activate each sheet):

```
Sub spellCheck()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ' Do stuff...
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I hadn't heard of .Activate. Seems redundant no?

Comment: So it's basically telling it to actually activate the sheet that is in the iteration. Otherwise, you still have a Worksheet object (with all the standard properties) but certain things you aren't able to do (like `ws.Cells.Activate`). However you still can do stuff like `ws.Range("A1") = "Hello"` without actually activating each sheet and it will still work. If your code does any activating/selecting of the cells on each sheet, I believe you actually have to activate it first. Does that make sense?