# macro that loops through worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

The macro below performs a calculation and generates a bar chart. At the moment it works for the first worksheet (Sheet1) I would like to be able to repeat the same macro on all worksheets in my excel workbook. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub MyReport()
     Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        Application.GetOpenFilename
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5])"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5])"
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5])"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])"
    Range("G1:I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$G$1:$I$2")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
End Sub
```

Comment: `Is there a simple way to do this?` - you could use [For Each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060855/iterating-through-excel-sheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to use a for each loop to apply code to each sheet.  I've also simplified some of your code.

```
Sub MyReport()
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

    For Each Ws In Wbk.Worksheets
        Ws.Range("G2:I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5])"
        Ws.Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])"

        Set chrt = Ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        chrt.SetSourceData Source:=Ws.Range("$G$1:$I$2")
        chrt.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

---

Results (sheet 1 shown):

[image]

Comment: Nice answer but I would `Dim` the `Ws` variable just for best practice.

Comment: Wait! :) Instead of `ActiveWorkbook` maybe it would be good to `Dim WB as WorkBook` and then `Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)` to include OP's initial code. **Edit:** you just got my +1 :)

Comment: @simpLEMAn I intentionally left that part out but your right, it would be better to stick with the original OP intentions.  Added to code.

Comment: Alright, it's also because I'm not a big fan of `ActiveWhatever` because you never know :)

Comment: Error handling is a part that change your code from "good" to "excelent":) What would be if user press "Cancel" or select "*.txt" file? See my [answer here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723223/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it/21723463#21723463):)

Comment: @OO_Learner; It is Portland Runner's solution :)